# Check if a resource of a type exists

Tags: azure-cli

I have a requirement to create a AZ CLI script to create a few resources and I would like to make it idempotent in a way that it checks if a resource exists before tries creating it.

The is what I have for creating an action group but my question is for checking any resource to see if it exists.

```
az monitor action-group create `
--name $ActionGroupName `
--resource-group $ResourceGroupName `
--short-name $AGShortName
```

The below will throw error if the resource does not exist. How can I safely check if a resource exists?

```
az monitor action-group show `
--name $ActionGroupName `
--resource-group $ResourceGroupName `
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Powershell - Check to see if resource exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076601/azure-powershell-check-to-see-if-resource-exists)

Comment: @easleyfixed That's for PowerShell, this question is for az CLI. So no, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh I thought you would have the rights to run a shell command to find out, my bad, hope there is a cli one.

Comment: What about this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458034/azure-cli-how-to-check-if-a-resource-exists?rq=2

Comment: That is az group specific. We don't have an `exists` method for other resources. Hence, the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command for a graceful wait:

```
az resource wait --exists --name "nameofactiongroup" \
--resource-group "resourcegroupname" \
--resource-type "actiongroups" \
--namespace Microsoft.Insights
```

The above command will wait till that particular resource is created/exists

You can find more options about that command:
az resource wait --help

[image]

Comment: This throws error if the resource does not exist. I would like to do that check safely. Thanks.

Comment: it will not throw error , it waits till the resource gets created. I did test it locally